# PyQt5 Signals and Threading

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I watched a short tutorial on PyQt4 signals on youtube and am having trouble getting a small sample program running. How do I connect my signal being emitted from a thread to the main window?

```
import cpuUsageGui
import sys
import sysInfo
from PyQt5 import QtCore

"""Main window setup"""
app = cpuUsageGui.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = cpuUsageGui.QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = cpuUsageGui.Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)

def updateProgBar(val):
    ui.progressBar.setValue(val)

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = sysInfo.getCpu()
            self.emit(QtCore.pyqtSignal('CPUVALUE'), val)

threadclass = ThreadClass()

# This section does not work
connect(threadclass, QtCore.pyqtSignal('CPUVALUE'), updateProgBar)
# This section does not work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threadclass.start()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signal must be created, inside your ThreadClass, or before but as you emit the signal inside the ThreadClass, it is better to create it inside your class.

After creation, you need to connect it to the progress bar function. Here is an example of the signal created and connected inside your class.

```
class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    # Create the signal
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

        # Connect signal to the desired function
        self.sig.connect(updateProgBar)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = sysInfo.getCpu()

            # Emit the signal
            self.sig.emit(val)
```

Keep in mind that signals have changed style since PyQt5 : [Description](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots)

if you watched a tutorial for PyQt4, it is not be the same.

Comment: Life saviour! Thank you very much!